# Mock module variable with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I've been using Jest to mock some variables, which are used in tested functions, like so:

```
global.SERVER_URL = 'test';
await hydrateApp();
expect(ReactDOM.hydrate).toBeCalled();
```

Here, the newly set value of `SERVER_URL` is used by `hydrateApp()`. However, I cannot do this with `module`. When I try to set `module.hot`, it will still be undefined, when the function is called:

```
global.module.hot = {
  accept: jest.fn()
};
await hydrateApp();
expect(global.module.hot.accept).toBeCalled();
```

In this case, `module.hot` is undefined inside `hydrateApp()`.

How can I set variable on the module object to be used by a function being tested?

Comment: Can you show the code of `hydrateApp` or at least how do you use `module.hot` there? Is it throwing any error when you set `global.module.hot`?

Another thing to consider - check the environment that you use, there's chance that you use browser-like environment (and instead of `global`, you have `window`).

Comment: The `global.module.hot` variable is set correctly and exists in `hydrateApp()`, but I need `module.hot` to be set, as webpack uses that for hot module replacement. For every other variable, I can set `global.var` and then `var` will also be set. Here I cannot do that.

Comment: `global` definitely exists, as I use that for other variables and it isn't showing any errors when I set `global.module.hot`.

Comment: There's chance that your setter fails silently because `module` is undefined and you try to set `hot` property on undefined `module`. Did you try sth like: `global.module = { hot: { accept: jest.fn() } };`? Note one more level for the object

Comment: Nope, `module.hot` is still undefined :(

Comment: Try using Object.defineProperty then - `Object.defineProperty(global, 'module', { value: { hot: { accept: jest.fn() } }, writable: true });`

Comment: Same: `global.module.hot` is correctly set, but `module.hot` is not. Maybe it's not possible to overwrite it?